# Reaching a function inside GameScene() from another class in SpriteKit is not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have this function inside the GameScene class

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    func runGameOver() {
        self.removeAllActions()
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Bullet") {
            bullet, stop in
            bullet.removeAllActions()
        }

        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Enemy") {
            enemy, stop in
            enemy.removeAllActions()
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run the runGameOver function from another function in another class. The loseALife function gets called whenever the enemy leaves the screen taking 1 from livesNumber.

If I declared a variable/constant for GameScene as in
**let object = GameScene()**
then call the function using **object.runGameOver()** the app crashes, therefore, I'm calling it as shown below **GameScene().runGameOver()** but it doesn't work. How should I access that function?

```
class LivesSystem {
    func loseALife() {
        livesNumber -= 1

        if livesNumber == 0 {
            GameScene().runGameOver()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a new fake `GameScene()`, which of course is the wrong approach. To be able to interact with the *real* (the one currently presented) `GameScene` you might use the `NotificationCenter`, doing so:

1) In your GameScene let's observe for the gameover:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        super.sceneDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.init("game_over"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
            self?.runGameOver()
        }
    }

    func runGameOver() {
        self.removeAllActions()
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Bullet") {
            bullet, stop in
            bullet.removeAllActions()
        }

        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Enemy") {
            enemy, stop in
            enemy.removeAllActions()
        }
    }
}
```

2) In your `LivesSystem` whenever is needed, launch the notification with:

```
class LivesSystem {
    var livesNumber = 3

    func loseALife() {
        livesNumber -= 1

        if livesNumber == 0 {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init("game_over"), object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```